# copy cell from above if cell to the left is empty (arrayformula)

Tags: function, auto-update, array-formulas

Working sith google spreadsheet
I'm trying to convert this formula

`B2= IF ( A2="" ; B1 ; A2 )`

to

`B2= arrayformula( ? )`

I have an arrayformula working in older spreadshhet, but it's not woring in the new one.

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A;A2:A;MMULT(MATCH(ROW(A2:A);FILTER(ROW(A1:A);LEN(A1:A)))=TRANSPOSE(MATCH(FILTER(ROW(A1:A);LEN(A1:A));FILTER(ROW(A1:A);LEN(A1:A));0));FILTER(A1:A;LEN(A1:A)))) )`

Here is the example:

`__|____A___|____B___|
1 |   data |function| 
2 |      4 |      4 |
3 |        |      4 |
4 |      1 |      1 |
5 |        |      1 |
6 |        |      1 |
7 |      5 |      5 |
8 |      7 |      7 |
9 |        |      7 |`

Can someone help me convert my normal function to an arrayformula function?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my answer on productforums.google.com

```
=ArrayFormula(if(row(A2:A) <= max(if(not(isblank(A2:A)); row(A2:A)));vlookup(row(A2:A);filter({row(A2:A)\A2:A};len(A2:A));2);))
```